# Python - How does argument 'function' affect a list when using shuffle

Tags: python, random, shuffle

When you use `shuffle(x, random)`, you have two parameters: the list and the function. By default, the function is `random()`, which returns a random value between 0 and 1.

Now, what I would like to know is, how does this affect the list? If, for example, I assign a function to return a specific value in such way like the following:

```
import random

def myfunction():
  return 0.1

mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
random.shuffle(mylist, myfunction)

print(mylist) #Prints: ['banana', 'cherry', 'apple']
```

What will happen? From what I've seen, the way the list is organized changes. So, If I, once again, determine the value the function returns, will It be organized differently?

```
import random

def myfunction():
  return 0.9

mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
random.shuffle(mylist, myfunction)

print(mylist) #Prints: ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
```

Whereas If return a value such as 0.89, the way the list is organized does not change. This leads to my doubt.

I probably made some vague assumptions, but It's the best explanation I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about the `random` argument or use it in any new code as it has been deprecated in Python 3.9:

> [`random.shuffle(x[, random])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)
>
> Shuffle the sequence `x` in place.
>
> The optional argument `random` is a 0-argument function returning a
> random float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, this is the function [random()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random).
>
> ...
>
> *Deprecated since version 3.9, will be removed in version 3.11: The optional parameter random.*

If you are interested in how it works anyway here is the actual **[source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py#L348)** that makes it pretty clear:

```
def shuffle(self, x, random=None):
        """Shuffle list x in place, and return None.
        Optional argument random is a 0-argument function returning a
        random float in [0.0, 1.0); if it is the default None, the
        standard random.random will be used.
        """

        if random is None:
            randbelow = self._randbelow
            for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
                # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
                j = randbelow(i + 1)
                x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
        else:
            _warn('The *random* parameter to shuffle() has been deprecated\n'
                  'since Python 3.9 and will be removed in a subsequent '
                  'version.',
                  DeprecationWarning, 2)
            floor = _floor
            for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
                # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
                j = floor(random() * (i + 1))
                x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```